# c# ASP.Net Membership WebForm Email Verification

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning how to use the ASP.net membership and i would like the user to first verify his email by having an email sent to him before his account is enabled allowing him to login.

There is a tutorial here https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153319/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx

However i'm finding it hard to follow, could someone pls explain how i can do this and if possible link to a C# tutorial. It's odd there isent many tutorials on c# ASP.net working wiht Membership WebForm in terms of this and creating profile pages ect, the usual things you would see on a normal website.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are reading the article from 11. please read all the 18 articles.

ASP.NET has some tutorials on Membership under the section Security here http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

Also if you are inclined to watching video tutorials, try these. Here is a sample video http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-set-up-the-sql-membership-provider

Comment: It's because the code is in VB i think anyway. I know how to setup a membership provider i just don't know how to make an email verification feature. And yes video tutorials are easiest to follow but again its VB i stated in the title C# and in the tags C#. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you check below the video you can find the code and pdf in c#

Comment: I know how to setup a membership provider :/. Ive just skimmed the video doesent give help on setting up email verification. Prob my fualt for not making it clear at the start that i already have the database setup and the membership.

Answer (score 0):

In this video, Joe Stagner extends the registration process in an ASP.NET application by adding an email verification step.

[Implement the Registration Verification Pattern](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/implement-the-registration-verification-pattern)